# Creating a Stacked Pareto in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, dashboard, ssrs-2016

I work in a manufacturing environment.  We record defects (scrap and rework) on parts for 9 different reasons (eg Weld Fault).  I need to chart this for a dashboard in SSRS.

In SSRS, I am pulling the data out into a stacked bar chart so I can see total defects per defect type (and it's split by Scrap / Rework) , and this works great, however I want it to appear as a Stacked Pareto format (so, most common on the left, and reduces down to the right)

I'm relatively new to SSRS so this is a learning curve.  I'm guessing I need to do something with the Running Value - I've looked at using this to sort by, but according to the error received I cannot sort by RunningValue.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could create a stacked Pareto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have a stacked barchart, but it is not sorted largest to smallest.

All you should need to do is right mouse click on your category group, then click on the sorting tab then enter into the Expression something like

=Count(Fields!Type.Value)

or

=Sum(Fields!Items.Value)

Depending on whether your bars sum a field or are counts of records in your dataset. It should be the same as the series calculation, ie what highlighted below

[image: Total]

To make largest to smallest you will need to change the sort order to Z to A.

Comment: Thanks, cabbage.  Finally got an opportunity to do this.  Yes, I currently have a stacked chart. My fields are (top to bottom in your image) - DefectCount, FailureCode, ScanResult.  I followed your guide, added the function `=SUM(Fields!DefectCount).Value` to the Category Group sorting, and ran it.  Unfortunately I get the error "The Sort expression for the grouping ‘Chart4_CategoryGroup’ uses an aggregate function with an expression that returned a data type not valid for the aggregate function. (rsProcessingError)".  DefectCount is an integer.

Comment: The .Value needs to be inside the brackets, but that might be a typo on your part? If you type the expression directly into the Sort By box (without clicking on the Fx button to open the expression window), you can type Sum(DefectCount)

Comment: Typo by me, well spotted - that fixed it.  Thanks cabbage - very much appreciated